# Evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^{2} \sin(x^2*\pi) dx$

Tags: integration

> I have no idea how to do this integral:
>
> $$\int_{0}^{2} \sin(x^2\pi) dx$$

Can you please tell me how to calculate the definite integral?
thanks

Comment: It is not possible to get an elementary function for this integral. Maple gives an answer that contains a Fresnel function.

Comment: Use a numerical approximation method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \int_{0}^{2}\sin\left(\pi x^2\right)\,dx =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{2\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x^2\right)\,dx =\color{red}{\frac{S\left(2\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}} \approx 0.2743355 $$ [Fresnel Integral](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FresnelS%5B2Sqrt%5B2%5D%5D%2FSqrt%5B2%5D).

Answer (score -1):

note that:
$$\int_0^2\sin(x^2\pi)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(u^2)du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}dx$$
and this can easily be expressed as a series